# What defines the maximum size of a global array in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, global-variables

Let's say I declare a global array in my C program (i.e. it's not allocated in stack memory).

What is the largest array I can create? Is it just a limitation of available memory on the machine? Or is there some other OS setting that typically controls this?

Comment: You may not declare a variable length array with static storage duration.

Comment: The MS Visual C 32-bit compiler allows a total of about 2 GB for *all* purposes.

Comment: There will be a number of different factors, depending on the compiler, OS, platform, etc.

Comment: From C perspective, a maximum size for an object can be `SIZE_MAX` bytes.

Comment: If you want big arrays, use `malloc` which on some systems will over-commit.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry, I didn't mean variable in the sense that the array size would change. I updated the question title.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The C standard does not limit object sizes to `SIZE_MAX`. `SIZE_MAX` is the largest value representable in `size_t`, and `size_t` is the type for `sizeof` expressions, and `size_t` is undoubtedly intended to represent sizes of types, but the standard does not explicitly prohibit overflowing sizes, any more than it prohibits overflowing `int` arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single largest bound on an array size in C. In any particular implementation, it may be limited by actually available memory (either main memory or swap space on disk, according to operating system features and settings), policy set by the system operator, capability of the address space, limitations of the compiler, and possibly other factors.

The limit may be available memory in one system and address space in another system.

Comment: Is there any way to check this limit? Or will it just result in undefined behavior by the program?